# jQuery Datatable functionality not working when I call another function in document ready

Tags: jquery, laravel-livewire

Hello guys when I call another function (Open modal or delete) the DataTable is not working.

Here is my whole script.

```
<script>

//Contacts

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rolesTable').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        stateSave: true
    });
} );

window.livewire.on('closeRoleModal', () => {
    $('#roleModal').modal('hide');
});

window.livewire.on('openRoleModal', () => {
    $('#roleModal').modal('show');
});

//delete contact
window.addEventListener('swal:confirmRoleDelete', event => {
    swal.fire({
        title: event.detail.title,
        text: event.detail.text,
        icon: event.detail.icon,
        showCancelButton: event.detail.showCancelButton,
        confirmButtonColor: event.detail.confirmButtonColor,
        cancelButtonColor: event.detail.cancelButtonColor,
        confirmButtonText: event.detail.confirmButtonText,
    }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
        window.livewire.emit('deleteRole',event.detail.id)
        swal.fire(
        'Deleted!',
        'Your file has been deleted.',
        'success'
        )
    }
    });
});

//

</script>
```

I tried to put another document.ready but still now working.

Answer (score 0):

if you are dispatching the event from component to front using the dispatchBrowserEvent

```
//component
   $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closeRoleModal');
   // or
   $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('openRoleModal');

//blade
window.addEventListener('closeRoleModal', event => {
    $('#roleModal').modal('hide');
});

window.addEventListener('openRoleModal', event => {
    $('#roleModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: I tried to change the approach but still you need to refresh the page so that the dataTable will be working